# ACS skilled employment criteria for 2 years university degree

Tags: australia, employment, skilled-migration

According to ACS (Australian Computer Society) booklet named "Skills Assessment Guidlines for Applicants - Augost 2017"

> All relevant work experience completed after the Skill Level Requirement Met Date will be considered Skilled Employment and eligible for points under the skilled migration points test.
>
> The work experience required to meet the suitability criteria is NOT included as Skilled Employment and is NOT eligible for points under the skilled migration points test.
>
> The ACS assessment process will seek to find the earliest Skill Level Requirement Met Date possible for each assessment type

I hold an Advanced Diploma (14 years degree, 12 years of school and 2 years of university) in Computer Software. The document clearly says (in an example in page 5) that if you hold a Bachelors degree (3-4 years university), 2 years of work experience will be used to satisfy the suitability criteria. I want to know how many years will satisfy considering my degree?

Someone told me 5 years of work will be used, I hope that is false news and they take only 2, otherwise I lose very important points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That person was correct. If you do not hold a bachelor's degree, it's 5 years within the last 10 years or 6 years over your entire work history (AKA some work experience is more than 10 years old) if the diploma, advanced diploma, or associate degree is closely related to your nominated occupation.

See the [Summary of Criteria](https://www.acs.org.au/content/dam/acs/acs-skills/Summary%20of%20Criteria%20-%202017.pdf) pdf and look for the first orange box.